# Authenticating user for IdentityServer on the WebApi side

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, autofac, identityserver3, katana

I am new at this. Can someone please help me, since I am going crazy over my problem for nearly a month now :(
In short: I have identity server project, an webapi project and angular client. Client request to authenticate and gets id_token and access_token (all good), access_token send to webapi project where I have:

```
var idServerBearerTokenAuthOptions = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions  {
            Authority = "https://localhost:11066/IdentityServer/identity",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
            AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "permissions", "openid" },
            DelayLoadMetadata = true
        };
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(idServerBearerTokenAuthOptions);
```

and I have Autofac which should get me the current logedin user

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();
builder.Register(c => new ClaimsIdentityApiUser((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity)).As<IApiUser>().InstancePerRequest();
```

BUT Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity has nothing, and
also ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity has nothing. What am I missing??

p.s. Similar problem to this question [Protecting webapi with IdentityServer and Autofac - can't get claims](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38712088) but obviously not same solution nor set up.

Comment: Have you tried looking at HttpContext.User instead of the thread user?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Travis. I believe this also is meant to be used at the controllers (like RequestContext), but I want to identify the user in the owin pipeline. Or am I wrong? (in that case please give me a short example)

Comment: This may be obvious, but have you added the authorise attribute? Without it, there's nothing to force authentication & the identity will be null

Comment: @SimonHalsey I want to take the user before it reaches the call to the controllers (the api methods which need to be authorized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) user should always be retrieved from ApiController.User (or the RequestContext)
b) token validation might fail for some reason use this resource to enable logging for the token validation middleware:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/diagnostics.html

c) are you using JWTs or reference tokens? For JWTs you can set the ValidationMode to Local

Comment: Thanks Dominick for the reply but...
a) I want to get the user very sooner in the owin pipeline  (after app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(idServerBearerTokenAuthOptions);) or is this not possible (I have bad design)? 

b) Tried adding it the suggestion in the web.config, but no log. Where should the file be logged?

c) yes it is a JWT token. Tried with ValidationMode local, still the same result, but it depend of a

Comment: p.s. b) I manually created **katana.trace.log** in the project root and the solution root, but nothing is logged

Comment: In the Katana pipeline you access the current use via OwinContext.Authentication.User. For the logging - that's just standard .NET logging - you should be able to get that to work

Comment: It seems I have a problem with authentication -
**"Error returned from introspection endpoint: An error occurred while sending the request."**   Which is nor descriptive nor I don't understand what introspective endpoint is, but according to this https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/introspection.html I don't use that.

Will investigate more in the next days, now I have some else work to do, but a hint is welcomed :)

Comment: Start with setting the validation mode to local.

Comment: @leastpriviledge - ok, it seems it works now. You input helped and that's why I marked it as answer. What I have done:

1. Enable logging (I will do this now always first)
2. I found out there was a failure in token validation do to a no proper ssl setup (I believe this should go in identity server docs).
3. Had a wrongly configurated string which guided my API project to a wrong discovery document.
4. End up using HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity
5. At the moment the ValidationMode is set to Local

so thanks again for the help